# Extracting strings of a list in pandas column as integer or float

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have column A in DF data frame. Current;y, it looks like this:

```
      A
1    [32000, 56000, 12000] 
2    [32000, 12000]
3    []
4    [25]
.
.
```

Some cells are empty list. I want to extract values as integer or float for each row and sum the total value. I attempted doing this and got the message below:

```
[[float(i) for i in k]  for k in DF['A'] ]

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

What I want:

```
A
1 100000
2 44000
3 0 and so on.
```

I am posting some results based on the suggestions:

```
import ast
DF.A.apply(ast.literal_eval)  (ValueError: malformed node or string: [])

DF.A.head().to_dict()
```

returns:

```
{0: [],
 1: ['32000', '56000', '12000'],
 2: [],
 3: [],
 4: ['2000', '1500', '1000', '10', '1000']}
```

Note: I created dataframe from customer narratives. I tried to clean punctuations and irrelevant characters.  A narrative goes like below for each row.

" XYZ foo bar foo XYZ { $130 }  XYX bar foo { $260 }"  or
"XYZ bar foo"  (no dollars mentioned in this one). All of these are rows

I created a new column to represent the dollar value mentioned. I reduced the narrative to number-only as explained above.

Also, if I can extract the sum of total dollar value mentioned for each row's narrative without going through cleaning the narrative (to avoid potential problems), that would work too. I tried to do some regex on the raw narrative but failed to extract the amounts indicated in between {$ }--this is how dollar value represented in each row narrative.

Comment: If you still need help, please provide a [mcve]. The example should include how you create the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as following, where `apply` with `ast.literal_eval` (*if 'A' is string representation of list*) for string to `list`. And then apply `sum`:

```
import ast

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(ast.literal_eval) # iff A is string representation of list
df['A'].apply(sum)
```

Result:

```
1    100000
2     44000
3         0
4        25
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a custom function which maps elements to `int` and then applies `sum`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['32000', '56000', '12000'],
                         ['32000', '12000'],
                         [],
                         ['25']]})

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, x)))

print(df)

        A
0  100000
1   44000
2       0
3      25
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension:

```
df['A'] = [sum(map(int, x)) for x in df['A']]
```

Another solution is to create a dataframe of numeric values and then sum over an axis:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist()).fillna(0).astype(int)\
       .sum(axis=1)\
       .to_frame('A')
```

#### Update

With your updated series data, the last option appears viable:

```
s = pd.Series({0: [],
               1: ['32000', '56000', '12000'],
               2: [],
               3: [],
               4: ['2000', '1500', '1000', '10', '1000']})

res = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist()).fillna(0).astype(int)\
        .sum(axis=1)\
        .to_frame('A')

print(res)

        A
0       0
1  100000
2       0
3       0
4    5510
```

Comment: I tried all of these suggestions after your post. For the first one, I got ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. Then I tried float instead of int. I got this: 
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: The last returned AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fillna'. Probably, it is my data. There may be weird values in these lists since I am doing NLTK. Thanks for the hep though.

Comment: @worthy, Looks like you need to define your dataframe precisely; for example, try `df.head().to_dict()` and paste the results into your question, which you can [edit here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50892465/edit).

Comment: I posted additional results per your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @worthy, I've updated taking precisely the data you've provided.